# If database is containing large data, retrieving JSON page URL showing blank

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, database

I am working on project for convert website to android app. At the first stage I need to passing all data from mysql database to android studio so that I am using php JSON method for data retrieving. Its working fine when less data or very few data onto databse but if I input a big amount of data into my database than the JSON page url preview totally blank.

Actually this is an e-commerce site and working fine if 15-20 product in the database but when I upload more than 20 or 30 products than no data retrieving into JSON page and when I browse JSON page url into web browser than showing totally blank page. Please help me how can I retrieving all data from mysql database. there are more than 20,000+ products in the database and I need to all of data retrieving JSON and parse into android app.

Comment: There is no need to load all the products. Not every visitor wants/needs to see all the products. Give the visitor a list of categories. Let them select one and then show a limited number of entries for that category. Use pagination to load the next lot of products from the selected category.

Comment: yes, but per category having more than 2000 products, it is also large. and I don't know how to retrieving JSON data limited in one page, actually page concept for JSON data. How to create page for JSON data for limited products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your SQL query and specify limit and offset

```
LIMIT 20 OFFSET offVal
```

And in your android request just add it in your request, then add a next button that would redirect to another request,

For example using
**GET REQUEST**

Just add this to your url and receive it in your php backend.

`&offset=1`

Then on your NEXT button onclick just recall the request with incremented offset

`&offset=21`

**NOTE:** Just adjust increment according to your SQL limit. Hope this gives you an idea